# Regarding Anaconda's python and native macOS python

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to anaconda and the concept of environments and have a few questions I want to clarify!

1. Does the Anaconda graphical installer installs a new "copy" of python into my Mac?
2. So, in the future, am I correct to say that when I update packages/python through Conda, it will not affect my native python version? (and therefore will not affect my macOS "dependencies"?)
3. Should I be creating a new environment for my learning instead of using the base environment? (b/c Conda documentation states that

> When you begin using conda, you already have a default environment named base. You don't want to put programs into your base environment, though. Create separate environments to keep your programs isolated from each other.

Comment: Also, when I type " pip list"  it comes from anaconda not the native one anymore?

Comment: Please don't use the comment function to add additional detail to your own question, instead use the edit button

Comment: It is all about the `PATH`

Comment: Note, Anaconda is a python *distribution*. It comes packaged with the conda environment/package manager. When you create a new environment, it adds *another* interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you get a new copy of python that can also have a different version than the one shipped with you OS. `conda` will set up your `PATH` environment variable so that the new python will take precedence whenever you call `python`
2. Yes
3. That could be somewhat of an opinion based answer, but I would highly encourage it. It helps you to get used to the environment concept and also in case you mess something up, you can just delete an environment and create a new one
4. When you do `pip list` it will also show you packages that are in your currently active `conda` environment. This is again because `conda` has by default also installed `pip` and has modified the `PATH` so that condas pip is found when you do `pip` commands

Note: You can always check with the `which` command where commands are called from. When doing `which pip` or `which python` you should see that both point to your `anaconda` or `miniconda` installation directory

Comment: Is it ever a bad thing that Conda's python and pip takes precedence on the Mac terminal? Thank you so much for answering my queries!

Comment: @RyanSeah no, it isn't.

Comment: @RyanSeah feel free to accept the answer if it has answered your question